# Soft question: Primes and relative precision

Tags: prime-numbers, pi, ratio

To describe the relation in sizes of two values to each other, one could use fractions and division. 1 compared to 2, is the same as 1/2 or 1:2, and likewise, when describing 5 compared to 10, you could write 1/2 for clarity/brevity; not using the lowest power of common primes, is just less accurate overall.

But when It comes to less obvious ratios, you are forced to resort to higher numbers. 5/249th's is more precise than saying 1/50th't: larger values provide more precision.

PI is given as the ratio of circumference and diameter. And, given that there are infinite amounts of primes to be found, each adding some 'relative uniqueness', **how can we say for sure** that there is no prime 'unique' enough to describe the ratio of circumference and diameter precisely, without resorting to decimals?

Knowing that an infinite amount of primes exist, wont they eventually, written as x/large_prime, be able to describe a value less divisible than the ratio of PI? How do we know that there is no such (power of a) prime? When each new prime offer an increasing relative uniqueness.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here, but pi is irrational (transcendental, even), and any ratio of integers is rational. I do not know what you mean by 'a value less divisible than the ratio of PI', but pi is not a ratio of integers at all. Basically, can you clarify the question, using some more accurate terminology?

Comment: I do believe early attempts were made to find higher values to describe the ratio of circumference and diameter of a circle. The question is valid, even historically, I guess a way to put it could be, how do we know large enough number do not exist

Comment: By divisible, do you mean a ratio of two integers, i.e. 1.5 is 'divisible' because it can be written as 3/2? Divisible doesn't really make sense on its own like that; a is divisible by b means that a is an integer multiple of b. Also, just to clarify, pi cannot be expressed as the ratio of two integers. For proofs, just search 'proof that pi is irrational' or something similar.

Comment: you could say 1/50 instead of 5/249, just like they used to write PI, knowing the ratio to be an estimate. How do we know there is no 'estimate' that is precise, even though we have (powers of) primes that could be increasingly small/precise

Comment: I guess I have an idea that newfound primes offer relative uniqueness, and I'm wondering if that doesnt mean we should, eventually, be able to define PI without decimals

Comment: Well, yes of course you can express pi as a fraction to unlimited precision, for example just write n decimal digits of pi over $10^n$, or indeed do the same in any base, but it cannot be the exact value of pi.

Comment: powers of 2 or w/e arbitrary number wont offer unique ratios mind you, but higher and higher primes will, right? the key words being relative and unique, And since we know infinite primes exist, wont they be more and more suited to show 2 integer values, that relative to each other, will describe the circles diameter and circumference to a tee?

Comment: Yes, there are infinitely many primes, and so also infinitely many rational numbers. A rational number can be arbitrarily close to the value of pi, but never precisely it. So you are correct in the sense that ratios of numbers can get as close as you want to pi. (As a side note, the decimal representation of pi is really just another rational approximation of pi - it's not as if the decimal representation is somehow 'correct')

Comment: I'm just asking, because it seems to me, that primes offer a unique ratio: take 1:2, 1:3, 1:5 1:7 etc, and that 3:7 thus is un-describable without 3 and 7, so that each new prime will offer a possibility for another unique-ness, do you get the idea? if there is an infinite amount of primes, aka infinite precision, doesnt there somewhere exist a precies definition of pi? im certain archimedes or someone had the same idea. Im curious of how do we know there is not, in laymans terms

Comment: like this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html @stanleydodds

Comment: There isn't really a simple way to show you that pi cannot be written as one integer divided by another; the proofs are a bit too complex. But if you know, for example, the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (if you don't, look it up, because it's fairly simple to understand), then you can probably understand how it is possible to show that pi cannot be written as one integer divided by another.

Comment: @stanleydodds Isnt this a classical greek dilemma? to be downvoted for that =P